# Resistor identifications

Tags: resistors, identification

I’m in need of resistor identification.

This board is from a domestic AES 3way fridge from a motorhome. It was only produced for 1 year in Canada for the motorhomes. In its form the board was produced, put into a cover, then filled with a potting compound. I have managed to remove most of compound over a bit of time.

There are 2 resistors I need to replace and see if it will work again. It will work on gas and 12 V, but when the 230 V comes on it reaches its temperature, turns off with the AES system check, but does not come back on and goes to the gas setting when it should be on 230 V.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What has led you to believe that those resistors are the problem?  I assume the blue one was damaged during the potting compound removal.

Comment: Try https://duckduckgo.com/?q=resistor+color+code

Comment: Wow what happened to these. Anyway I see red-black-black-orange-(brown), and the broken one is unclearly red-red-red-red or red-red-orange-red? (no big difference between those codes) and the one that's somehow burned into the potting compound (???) is clearly blue-red-yellow or yellow-red-blue... that one is intact other than the outer casing, so you might be able to disconnect it and measure it